# Change the field value in Firestore automatically after a certain time

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on Javascript and here's how's my data looks like.
[image: Here the ss of my firestore]

I want the functionality where after every 24 hours, my stateChanges fields updates to 0. (see the circled field).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I can't understand how to work with cloud functions on web. I'm just requesting the timestamp help. Like how to write code where I can update the field after certain time. I have tried googling it. But there are no solutions for web. Only react, android studio and flutter etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality built-in in Firestore.

A possilbe solution would be to use [an HTTP Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) which will alternate state and invoke it with a [Cloud Scheduler cron job](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) every 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing would be to use a firebase cloud function for that - it's fairly easy to set up, and you can afterwards set up Cron jobs to perform regular scheduled activities.

You can find out more about cloud functions here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

The cloud function you need would look something like this:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
  admin.firestore().collection('stateInfo').get().then(snapshot=>{
     snapshot.forEach(doc=>doc.update({stateChanges:0}))
     })
  });
```

Here's the reference for scheduled functions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

And the cron expression (e.g. `0 0 * * *`) for scheduling can be generated here:
https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm using pure JavaScript. I have to use Node Cli for this functionality. So there's no built-in function. I marked the answer

Comment: @HanzalaSaeed This is pure javascript based on the the Firebase documentation. It's literally the same as the answer you marked, just that I included the actual function you need and additional information

Comment: Khulmann "You'll need a Node.js environment to write functions, and you'll need the Firebase CLI to deploy functions to the Cloud Functions runtime." This is what is written in point 2 of  cloud functions.  I cant use it without node

Comment: @HanzalaSaeed Cloud functions are serverless functions - yes, they run on node, but you don't need to run a node server. You simply use the Firebase cli to set up your local dev environment, write some javascript code and deploy it. Firebase/Google is then running the code for you, so it's pretty much the same as developing frontend code and then deploying that to firebase hosting. Here's some more information about serverless architecture: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/what-is-a-serverless-function/

Comment: Thanks for the resources. It was good to read and gain knowledge.